# Are there free online penetration testing labs that I can safely hack with my computer?

Tags: penetration-test

I have seen the offensive security penetration testing labs; they are amazing but costly. Is there any other online virtual penetration testing lab I can SAFELY conduct penetration testing and exploitation against? I do not mean machines I can download, I mean online labs or sites.

Comment: As you say online labs, are you talking web apps / web servers rather than  OS, or are you looking for online virtualised windows/linux labs?  if you are looking for web, then first take a look at hack yourself first (from Troy Hunt) and Hack This Site (that's a name, not an instruction ;- )  )

Comment: @iain I meant both, but operating systems are better

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are my favorites for practice:

- [GhostSec's pentest labs](http://www.gh0st.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) - Only VMs all hosted online.
- VulnHub VMs (only downloadable VMs)
- [root-me.org is pretty awesome](https://www.root-me.org/) - it's got both web challenges as well as hosted VMs that you can deploy and attack.
- [hackthissite](https://www.hackthissite.org/) - name says it all, we app pentesting.
- [CTF365](https://ctf365.com/) - As you've probably figured, they have year long CTFs. It's been some time since I last used them, so I'm not sure if they've started charging for even usage.
- [hacking-lab](https://www.hacking-lab.com/index.html)
- [Enigma Group](https://www.enigmagroup.org/)
- [Hack The Box](https://www.hackthebox.eu/) - A competitive platform.
- [OverTheWire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/)